# Postgres left joining 3 tables with a condition

Tags: postgresql, join

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT x.id 
FROM x
    LEFT JOIN (
         SELECT a.id FROM a
         WHERE [condition1] [condition2]
    ) AS A USING (id)
    LEFT JOIN (
         SELECT b.id FROM b
         WHERE [condition1] [condition3]
    ) AS B USING (id)
    LEFT JOIN (
         SELECT c.id FROM c
         WHERE [condition1] [condition4]
    ) AS C USING (id)
    WHERE [condition1]
```

As you can see the `[condition1]` is common for subqueries and the outer query.

When [in general] might it be worth to remove `[condition1]` from subqueries (as the result is same) for performance reasons? Please don't give answers like "run it and see". There are lots of data and its changing so we need good worst case behaviour.

I have tried to do some tests but they are far from being conclusive. Will Postgres figure out that the condition applied to subqueries as well and propagate it?

Examples for `condition1`:

- `WHERE a.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM {ft_geom_in})` (this is slow, I know, this is just for example)
- `WHERE a.id > x`

Comment: `EXPLAIN`ing some queries on a smaller schema should prove informative. It'll depend quite a bit on the condition you're hoping to have pulled up into the outer query and on what index(es) are able to help. In general I suspect that running the condition only in the left join subqueries will be better if there aren't any relevant indexes, but may be less useful if there are appliccable indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to give a clear general answer, since much depends on the actual data model (especially indexes) and queries (conditions). 
However, in many cases it makes sense to place `condition1` in joined subqueries. 
This applies particularly when `condition2` excludes much less rows than `condition1`. 
In such cases, the filter on `condition1` may significantly reduce the number of checks of `condition2`.

On the other hand, it seems unlikely that the presence of `condition1` in subqueries could substantially slow down the query.

Simple tests do not give general answers, but might serve as an illustration.

```
create table x (id integer, something text);
create table a (id integer, something text);

insert into x select i, i::text from generate_series (1, 1000000) i;
insert into a select i, i::text from generate_series (1, 1000000) i;
```

**Query A: `condition2` excludes few rows.**

*A1: with `condition1`*

```
explain analyse
select x.id 
from x
    left join (
         select id from a
         where id < 500000 and length(something) > 1
    ) as a using (id)
where id < 500000;

Average execution time: ~620.000 ms
```

*A2: without `condition1`*

```
explain analyse
select x.id 
from x
    left join (
         select id from a
         where length(something) > 1
    ) as a using (id)
where id < 500000;

Average execution time: ~810.000 ms
```

**Query B: `condition2` excludes many rows.**

*B1: with `condition1`*

```
explain analyse
select x.id 
from x
    left join (
         select id from a
         where id < 500000 and length(something) = 1
    ) as a using (id)
where id < 500000;

Average execution time: ~220.000 ms
```

*B2: without `condition1`*

```
explain analyse
select x.id 
from x
    left join (
         select id from a
         where length(something) = 1
    ) as a using (id)
where id < 500000;

Average execution time: ~230.000 ms
```

Note, that the queries do not need to have subqueries. Queries with simple left joins and conditions in a common `where clause` should be a little bit faster. For example, this is the equivalent of query B1:

```
explain analyse
select x.id 
    from x
    left join a using(id)
    where x.id < 500000
    and a.id < 500000 
    and length(a.something) = 1

Average execution time: ~210.000 ms
```

Comment: thanks for a detailed response.  As you said it really depends on distribution of data, probably your answer cannot be improved without going to details about how query planner works